# SDL OpenGL Texture display issue

Tags: qt, opengl, sdl, textures

I'm following [this tutorial](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL:Tutorials:Using_SDL_with_OpenGL) in order to *Load an OpenGL Texture from an SDL_Surface*, I've copy/paste code and adapted it but it only display wrong old part of the buffer which is a little bit annoying... Cause I can't figure what's wrong. Also I work with Qt5 on Mac Os X. Here's my code

```
GLuint texture;         // This is a handle to our texture object
SDL_Surface *surface;   // This surface will tell us the details of the image
GLenum texture_format;
GLint  nOfColors;
surface = IMG_Load("/brique.png");

if ( surface ) {

    // get the number of channels in the SDL surface
    nOfColors = surface->format->BytesPerPixel;
    if (nOfColors == 4)     // contains an alpha channel
    {
        if (surface->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
            texture_format = GL_RGBA;
        else
            texture_format = GL_BGRA;
    } else if (nOfColors == 3)     // no alpha channel
    {
        if (surface->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
            texture_format = GL_RGB;
        else
            texture_format = GL_BGR;
    } else {
        printf("warning: the image is not truecolor..  this will probably break\n");
        // this error should not go unhandled
    }

    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    // Have OpenGL generate a texture object handle for us
    glGenTextures( 1, &texture );

    // Bind the texture object
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );

    // Set the texture's stretching properties
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

    // Edit the texture object's image data using the information SDL_Surface gives us
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, nOfColors, surface->w, surface->h, 0, texture_format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels );
}
else {
    printf("SDL could not load image.bmp: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    SDL_Quit();
    exit (1);
}

// Free the SDL_Surface only if it was successfully created
if ( surface ) {
    SDL_FreeSurface( surface );
}
```

and here's the result : [image: bad display]

And here's the debug from the function glTexImage2D [image: debug session]

Comment: Have you step debugged this to see exactly what code is running and what is passed into `glTexImage2D`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably or did not declare a (this flips the **screen buffer**)

```
SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
```

Doing so putting it on the last part of the loop:

```
qglClearColor(qtPurple.dark());

/****************************************
... some ogl initialization code here ...
****************************************/

while (!done)
{
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   /***********************************
   ... some ogl rendering code here ...
   ***********************************/

   SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
}
```

Check this tutorial on QT5 OGL:

- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtopengl/hellogl.html

Comment: Have you ever called a **glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)** and **qglClearColor** (for QT5)?

Comment: Where am I suppose to call them? before rendering?

Comment: glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) - just below / inside the while loop. qglClearColor before the OpenGL initialization for QT5 clear buffer.

Comment: It's far better, you should post it as an answer :)